# Configuring an enum in Spring using application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    NAME("Name", "Good", 100),
    FAME("Fame", "Bad", 200);

    private String lowerCase;
    private String atitude;
    private long someNumber;

    MyEnum(String lowerCase, String atitude, long someNumber) {
        this.lowerCase = lowerCase;
        this.atitude = atitude;
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }
}
```

I want to set up the `someNumber` variable differently for both instances of the enum using `application.properties` file.

Is this possible and if not, should I split it into two classes using an abstract class/interface for the abstraction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well what you can do is the following:

1. Create a new class: **MyEnumProperties**

   ```
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "enumProperties")
   @Getter
   public class MyEnumProperties {

       private Map<String, Long> enumMapping;

   }
   ```
2. Enable ConfigurationProperties to your SpringBootApplication/ any Spring Config via

   ```
   @EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyEnumProperties.class)
   ```
3. Now add your numbers in **application.properties** file like this:

   ```
   enumProperties.enumMapping.NAME=123
   enumProperties.enumMapping.FAME=456
   ```
4. In your application code autowire your properties like this:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private MyEnumProperties properties;
   ```
5. Now here is **one way** to fetch the ids:

   ```
   properties.getEnumMapping().get(MyEnum.NAME.name()); //should return 123
   ```

You can fetch this way for each Enum value the values defined in your `application.properties`

Answer (score 4):

You can't/shouldn't change values of a enum in Java. Try using a class instead:

```
public class MyCustomProperty { 
    // can't change this in application.properties
    private final String lowerCase;
    // can change this in application.properties
    private String atitude;
    private long someNumber;

    public MyCustomProperty (String lowerCase, String atitude, long someNumber) {
        this.lowerCase = lowerCase;
        this.atitude = atitude;
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }
    // getter and Setters
}
```

Than create a custom [ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.config")
public class MyConfigConfigurationProperties {
    MyCustomProperty name = new MyCustomProperty("name", "good", 100);
    MyCustomProperty fame = new MyCustomProperty("fame", "good", 100);

    // getter and Setters

    // You can also embed the class MyCustomProperty here as a static class. 
    // For details/example look at the linked SpringBoot Documentation
}
```

Now you can change the values of `my.config.name.someNumber` and `my.config.fame.someNumber` in the application.properties file. If you want to disallow the change of lowercase/atitude make them final.

Before you can use it you have to annotate a `@Configuration` class with **`@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigConfigurationProperties.class)`**. Also add the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor` as an optional dependency for a better IDE Support.

If you want to access the values:

```
@Autowired
MyConfigConfigurationProperties config;
...
config.getName().getSumeNumber();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, it is exactly what I needed.