# Limiting possible values in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to limit in **application.properties** possible values e.g.

"**condition** = " to "*YES*" and "NO*"*, to later is this *YES/NO* as `enum` in code, 
but I get "Failed to convert value of type '`java.lang.String`' to required **type**".

How can I achieve it?

```
public enum PossibleConditions {
    YES,
    NO
}
```

Comment: what was the previous code?? please provide that.

Answer (score 3):

> Create a new class : **MyNewEnumProperties**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "enumProperties")
@Getter
public class MyNewEnumProperties{

    private Map<String, Long> enumMapping;

}
```

> Enable `ConfigurationProperties` to your SpringBootApplication/ any
>   Spring Config via

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = MyNewEnumProperties.class)
```

> Now add your stuffs in `application.properties` file like this:

```
enumProperties.enumMapping.YES=1
enumProperties.enumMapping.NO=0
```

> In your application code autowire your properties like this:

```
@Autowired
private MyNewEnumProperties properties;
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814770/configuring-an-enum-in-spring-using-application-properties)

Answer (score 0):

The property value (in the configuration) should be exactly like one of the values of the enum (perhaps you have a typo in the "NO" - the extra *).

All you need to do to the get the property is this:

```
@Value("${condition}")
private PossibleConditions condition;
```

See working example project (very light) [here in github](https://github.com/elirandav/springAsyncServlet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springAsyncServlet/MyCallableController.java).

In case the value of the property in `application.properties` is not exactly `YES` or `NO`, then you would get the parsing error and the app won't start (and I guess that is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `PropertyEditorSupport` class like this

```
public class PossibleConditionsEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    public void setAsText(final String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        switch (text) {
            case "YES": setValue(PossibleConditions.YES);
                        break;
            case "NO": setValue(PossibleConditions.NO);
                       break;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Possible values are YES and NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `@Value()` with property name to inject value of `PossibleConditions`.

```
@Service
class YourService {

    @Value("${condition}")
    private PossibleConditions condition;
}
```